# How to run a service without opening any activity by clicking on FCM notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to push notification what I want is when a user clicks on the notification it should not launch any activity instead it should run a service in the background which will process notification data.

Thanks For Help.

Comment: Sure, you can start a service in notification click handler, just like starting any other service on Android.  What is the specific problem you're having with this?  Please edit the question to be clear, and show any code you have that isn't working the way you expect

Comment: @DougStevenson problem is with fcm push notification